# Couldn't find constraint layout and new version of android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am using android studio 1.0 and want to use Constraint  layout but it says you have to update to 2.0 .Help->check for updates-> shows download option only and i am not able to find Appearance and Behavior as well as its not in setting ..
Please help

Answer (score 1):

**About downloading the last version of Android Studio you can download it from this link : https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html**

> It includes the constraint layout Library itself. don't forget to update
>   your `Sdk`s using SDK Manager.

**An Image of my `SDK Manager` Program** :

[image: SDK Manager]

Comment: how to update the sdk ? is there any way to import old sdk ??

Comment: I didn't try that one, But it's better to update whole needed `sdk`s

Comment: @Aftabkhan if you are living in a country like Iran , you need to use Vpn (Because of Filtering) for updating `SDK`s using SDK Manager.

Comment: @Aftabkhan anytime ♥♥

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 1 doen't support that update. Just download the new Android Studio and install it. [Download link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)

Comment: and then i have to download sdk as well ? how to import that old sdk ?

Comment: No you don't. Download the IDE only.